# How to run docker-compose and docker on same network?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I run 2 docker containers. One is mongodb container. The other one is Node.js app container trying to connect to that mongodb container.

If I run by "npm run start" on node.js app without docker, it runs well. It connects to mongodb container using just "mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject".

But it doesn't work on dockerized node.js app. **It does connect to Mongo DB** on "mongoose.connect" method.

**But when I actually connect on browser after the compile, it says:**

```
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

It looks like there is a problem that node.js container connecting to mongodb container, so get nothing from it, so data is undefined as it says.

**The steps I did:**

By following command, I created mongodb container first:

```
sudo docker container run --name mymongodb --publish 27017:27017 -d mongo
```

Then, on node.js app, I simply:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

**My docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "2"
services:
  myapp:
    container_name: mycontainer
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    network_mode: host
```

What is the problem of error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we do not use `network_mode: host` on dev.
By default docker-compose will create a network for your project and all containers can communicate using their container name.

If you want to access the containers from outside the network (from your browser for example), you use the `ports:` part to expose a container port to your host.

In your case, I will change your `docker-compose.yml` file for:

```
version: "2"
services:
  myapp:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
  mymongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb: {}
```

I add a volume to mongodb as well to keep the data when the container is deleted.

And update the connection string to mongodb for `mongodb://mymongo:27017/myproject` when using docker.
On your host, without docker, the connection string stay the same (`localhost` instead of `mymongodb`)